# How to edit footer content

Tags: footer

The theme I'm using doesn't allow me to edit the footer content and uses: `<?php get_sidebar(); get_footer(); ?>` instead of calling them separately, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

The theme I'm using is this one: http://pithoe.com/theme/?preview_theme=woddyx

Thank you kindly!

Comment: Is the footer of that theme not controlled by widgets?

Comment: Encrypted footer. Crap Theme, from a dirty, rotten, spammer developer. Try a Theme from the [official WPORG Theme repository](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes), instead.

Answer (score 2):

From OP comment:

> The footer.php file is all encrypted

**Do not download Themes from random sites**. [Only download Themes from trusted sources](http://www.chipbennett.net/2010/12/10/only-download-wordpress-themes-from-trusted-sources/), for exactly this reason.

The footer is encrypted, and the Theme is probably distributed under a license that prohibits modifying the footer. Thus, for *both* reasons, we cannot help you.

Answer (score 1):

Even Twenty Eleven calls these together:

```
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Normally you would inject content into the footer using one or more footer widget areas (sidebars), or by hooking the `wp_footer` action. Unfortunately, this theme does not call [`wp_footer()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer).

As you said, the footer file is obfuscated, but it's just plain text if you visit your blog and view the page source. Copy the source after `<!-- BEGIN footer -->`, clean it up, and drop it in footer.php. And also call `wp_footer()` at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you so much Adam, worked perfectly and all is fixed!

Answer (score 0):

`get_footer();` and `get_sidebar();` include the files `footer.php` and `sidebar.php` respectively. If you wish to edit the footer / sidebar  try editing `footer.php` or `sidebar.php`

Comment: Thanks. The footer.php file is all encrypted, and that's where the flicker photos, and newsletter stuff, etc are that I'd like to edit. Ahhh, why do they do this?!